# java multi threads access Hashtable

Tags: java, multithreading, hashtable

I tried to use multi threads to access the Hashtable, since Hashtable is thread safe on get. But I cannot get it work.

I thought the sum of local counter should be equal to the size of the Hashtable or the global_counter. But it is not.

Serveral threads get java.util.NoSuchElementException: Hashtable Enumerator error. I think the error is due to the enumeration of Hashtable. Is that so?

**TestMain:**

```
public class TestMain {

    // MAIN
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> id2 = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
            id2.put(i, i+1);

        int num_threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1;
        ExecutorService ExeSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num_threads);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
        {
            ExeSvc.execute(new CalcLink(id2, i));
        }

        ExeSvc.shutdown();
        ExeSvc.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

**CalcLink:**

```
public class CalcLink implements Runnable {

    private Hashtable<Integer, Integer> linktable;
    private static Enumeration keys;
    private static int global_counter;
    private int thread_id;
    private int total_size;

    public CalcLink(Hashtable<Integer, Integer> lt, int id)
    {
        linktable = lt;
        keys = lt.keys();
        thread_id = id;
        total_size = lt.size();
        global_counter = 0;
    }

    private synchronized void increment()
    {
        ++global_counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (keys.hasMoreElements())
        {
            ++counter;
            increment();
            Integer key = (Integer)keys.nextElement();
            Integer value = linktable.get(key);
        }

        System.out.println("local counter = " + Integer.toString(counter));

        if (thread_id == 1)
            System.out.println("global counter = " + Integer.toString(global_counter));
    }
}
```

Comment: Each individual operation might be thread-safe, but that doesn't mean it's thread-safe to do them one after the other without explicitly holding the lock.  (Additionally, `Hashtable` and `Enumeration` have been pretty much deprecated for at least 15 years at this point.)

Comment: Unfortunately concurrent programming isn't something that can be efficiently learnt through trial and error (as I found out to my own cost), I'd definitely find a good book or tutorial that gives a full overview of what's what, like Java Concurrency in Practice, or even the official Java tutorials.

Comment: What is the best/better way to use multithreads read the elements from Hashtable or HashMap?

Comment: @biziclop, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

```
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) // here you check whether there's an element
    {
        ++counter; // other stuff...
        increment(); // other stuff...
        Integer key = (Integer)keys.nextElement(); // only here you step
```

During you are in the other stuff in "this thread" you can enter the other stuff in another thread, thus IMHO you might see higher number in the global counter than what you expect.

This is also the reason you see NoSuchElementException in some of the threads, that entered to the "other stuff" together, but are trying to catch the last element. The later threads won't have the element there when they get to nextElement();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this block isn't synchronized :

```
while (keys.hasMoreElements())
{
    ++counter;
    increment();
    Integer key = (Integer)keys.nextElement();
    Integer value = linktable.get(key);
}
```

`keys.hasMoreElements()` can be evaluated to `true` in multiple threads when there is still only one element in the Enumeration. In those threads : the first one reaching `keys.nextElement()` will be fine, but all the others will raise a `NoSuchElementException`

Try this :

```
@Override
public void run() 
{
    int counter = 0;
    synchronized (keys){
        while (keys.hasMoreElements())
        {
          ++counter;
          increment();
          Integer key = (Integer)keys.nextElement();
          Integer value = linktable.get(key);
        }
     }

    System.out.println("local counter = " + Integer.toString(counter));

    if (thread_id == 1)
        System.out.println("global counter = " + Integer.toString(global_counter));
}
```

Comment: synchoronized(keys) does not help.

Comment: You still have NoSuchElementException ?

Comment: NoSuchElementException or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

An naive solution: I just let each thread to process Length / num_threads of records. Only the last thread will process length/num_threads + length%num_threads records.